# Compilar proceso principal ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, encriptación, electron, compilar

Es posible compilar el proceso principal de ElectronJS `main.js` con alguna herramienta? Estoy usando `nexe` para compilar el proceso principal `main.js` pero no funciona. ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo?

Estoy usando https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

Luego uso `nexe main.js` para generar un compilado de `main.js` con nombre `main.exe`

Luego modifico el `package.json` cambiando el valor de `main.js` a `main.exe`.

Finalmente ejecuto `npm start` y recibo un mensaje de error:

```js
MZ´┐¢


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1004:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at loadApplicationPackage (C:\Users\Onimac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:109:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Onimac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:155:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1004:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
```

Código main.js:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
})
```